# Cannot reach my server over the internet created with wamp (Virtual Host)

Tags: apache, wamp, virtualhost, wampserver

i cannot reach the server i put online with wampserver version 3.1.0. I have Windows 8.1 and 64 bit system.

My steps were:(chronologically not correct)

1. Click on wampicon and click put server online
2. Deactivate windows firewall completely
3. Deactivate antivirus (avira)
4. Make portforwarding of tp link Router (td W9970) for port 80
5. changed httpd.conf file to:

```
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 192.168.1.103:80
Listen 192.168.1.103:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

6. Change httpd-vhosts.conf file to:

```
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

All i can do is reaching to server with other device locally with local ip.

As soon as i enter my public ip into url line of a browser i get:
The connection has timed out

The server at [mypublicip] is taking too long to respond.

regardless of adding :80 for portnumber.

Comment: İs there nobody who can help?

Comment: İt seems like a difficult task